# Infinite Summation $\sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac {r^3+(r^2+1)^2}{(r^4+r^2+1)(r^2+r)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have been stuck on this summation for almost a week now and I'd really appreciate some help.
$$\sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac {r^3+(r^2+1)^2}{(r^4+r^2+1)(r^2+r)}$$

Comment: it would ne nice if you could add some own effort

Comment: adding  $+r^2-r^2=0$ to the numerator seems to be a good idea

Comment: No idea whether it helps , but $$\frac{r^3+(r^2+1)^2}{(r^4+r^2+1)(r^2+r)}=\frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{r+1}+\frac{1}{2(r^2-r+1)}-\frac{1}{2(r^2+r+1)}$$

Comment: @Peter this essentialy solves the problem

Comment: @Peter. Please post this comment as a **good** answer.

Comment: @tired I just noticed $$(r+1)^2-(r+1)+1=r^2+r+1$$ In fact, we can take two telescope-sums

Comment: @Peter post this as an answer i will gladly upvote it

Answer (score 3):

Hint : $$\frac{r^3+(r^2+1)^2}{(r^4+r^2+1)(r^2+r)}=\frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{r+1}+\frac{1}{2(r^2-r+1)}-\frac{1}{2(r^2+r+1)}$$

and $$(r+1)^2-(r+1)+1=r^2+r+1$$

You get two telescope sums , the result is $\frac{3}{2}$

Answer (score -1):

HINT:

$$r^4+r^2+1=(r^2+1)^2-r^2=?$$

Use [Partial Fraction Decomposition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html)

$$\frac {r^3+(r^2+1)^2}{(r^4+r^2+1)(r^2+r)}=\dfrac ar+\dfrac b{r+1}+\dfrac{cr+d}{r^2-r+1}+\dfrac{er+f}{r^2+r+1}$$

Now if $f(r)=r^2-r+1, f(r+1)=?$

See [Telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)